# Find the area of the circle that falls between the circle $x^2+y^2=5$ and the lines $x^2-4y^2+6x+9=0$

Tags: definite-integrals, analytic-geometry, area

> Find the area of the circle that falls between the circle $x^2+y^2=5$ and the lines $x^2-4y^2+6x+9=0$.

I tried to solve this question. The lines are $x-2y+3=0$ and $x+2y+3=0$ which intersect at $(-3,0)$ and the circle has its center at $(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt5$. The figure was asymmetric and calculations were difficult. So I shifted the origin to $(-3,0)$. In the new system the equations become $X+2Y=0$ and $X-2Y=0$ and the circle equation becomes $(X-3)^2+Y^2=5$. Now I found the point of intersection of lines and the circle which comes out to be $(\frac{4}{5},\frac{2}{5})$

Now when I integrate and required area is 4 times the integral $\int_{0}^{4/5}\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_{4/5}^{\sqrt5}\sqrt{5-(x-3)^2}dx$
but the answer $5(\pi-\arcsin\frac{4}{5})+\frac{24}{5}$ is still elusive and the calculations have not simplified even after origin shifting. Is the origin shifting futile. What is the correct way to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: You mean the circle tangent to the circle and the lines?
Maybe you can use the equation for the distance between a line and a point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: After the transformation $(x,y)\to (x-3,y)$, the circle's equation is $(x+3)^2+y^2=5$, and not $(x-3)^2+y^2=5$.

Comment: There is no good reason to shift origin. Draw a picture. Note the symmetry, we find the area of the top half and double.  Join the centre of the semicircle to the two points of intersection with the top line. We have divided the semi-circle into two sectors and a triangle. Now use geometry. Alternately one can integrate.

Comment: This might help http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2-4y%5E2%2B6x%2B9%3D0+and+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of equation $x-2y+3=0$ intersects the circle of equation $x^2+y^2=5$ at
$A(-\frac{11}{5},-\frac{2}{5})$ and $B(1,2)$. It follows that
$AB=\frac{8}{\sqrt{5}}$.

### $\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Using the notation of the figure we have $\sin\theta=\frac{AB}{2OA}=\frac{4}{5}$. That is $\theta=\arcsin\frac{4}{5}$. Moreover, $OH^2=5-\frac{16}{5}=\frac{9}{5}$, or $OH=\frac{3}{\sqrt5}$.

Now, $${\cal S}=\frac{\theta}{2}OA^2-\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot OH
=\frac{5}{2}\arcsin\frac{4}{5}-\frac{4}{\sqrt5}\frac{3}{\sqrt5}=
\frac{5}{2}\arcsin\frac{4}{5}-\frac{12}{5}$$
Finally the desired area is 
$${\frak A}=\pi(\sqrt5)^2-2{\cal S}=5\left(\pi-
\arcsin\frac{4}{5}\right)+\frac{24}{5}.$$
Which is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I may refer to sketch of Omran Kouba, you  need even not rotate each pink segment by $\pm \tan ^{-1} \frac12$, you can straightaway use the standard formula of area of circular segment ( subtract sector and triangle areas)..